# function won't work with input parameter value

Tags: function, if-statement, input, python-3.x

I'm working on something for school and for some reason this function, which calls all the rest of the functions, won't work.  You're supposed to be able to pick a function from the list and it will execute that function.  When I call the function as caller(3) or any other actual number, it will work fine.  Or if I say x = 3 then say caller(x) it works as well.  The thing that isn't working is if I ask for x = input('whatever')  caller(x).  It just spits out either nothing or "none" and it's getting really annoying.

I remade the first two functions so there would be something to actually call without copying the entire code in here.  If anyone can figure out what's going on I'd love some help.

```
def name_major():
    print('This one works')

def age_int():
    print('This one works too')

def caller(slct):
    select = slct
    if select == 1:
        name_major()
    elif select == 2:
        age_int()
    elif select == 3:
        n = randint(0,4)
        name_greet(randname[n])
    elif select == 4:
        messager('Bring out your dead! ', randint(1,8))
    elif select == 5:
        print('Function #5')
        get_biggest(randint(0,15),randint(0,15))
    elif select == 6:
        print('Function #6')
        wrd = input('Please enter a word or phrase: ')
        print('"' + str(wrd) + '" has', cap_counter(wrd), 'capital letters in it.')
    elif select == 7:
        n1 = randint(0,20)
        n2 = randint(0,20)
        n3 = randint(0,20)
        print(the_middler(n1,n2,n3))
    elif select == 8:
        run_all()

    x = input('give value')
    caller(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

`input` returns a string, and then you're comparing it to a series of integers.  You need to make it an `int`, or make the comparison targets into strings.

Compare

```
>>> x = input("give value: ")
give value: 17
>>> x
'17'
>>> type(x)
<class 'str'>
>>> x == 17
False
>>> x == '17'
True
```

with

```
>>> x = int(input("give value: "))
give value: 18
>>> x
18
>>> type(x)
<class 'int'>
>>> x == 18
True
```